# How to test and mock property wrappers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, property-wrapper

Let's say I have a very common use case for a property wrapper using `UserDefaults`.

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct DefaultsStorage<Value> {
    private let key: String
    private let storage: UserDefaults
    
    var wrappedValue: Value? {
        get {
            guard let value = storage.value(forKey: key) as? Value else {
                return nil
            }
            
            return value
        }
        
        nonmutating set {
            storage.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
    
    init(key: String, storage: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.key = key
        self.storage = storage
    }
}
```

I am now declaring an object that would hold all my values stored in `UserDefaults`.

```swift
struct UserDefaultsStorage {
    @DefaultsStorage(key: "userName")
    var userName: String?
}
```

Now when I want to use it somewhere, let's say in a view model, I would have something like this.

```swift
final class ViewModel {
    func getUserName() -> String? {
        UserDefaultsStorage().userName
    }
}
```

Few questions arise here.

1. It seems that I am obliged to use `.standard` user defaults in this case. How to test that view model using other/mocked instance of `UserDefaults`?
2. How to test that property wrapper using other/mocked instance of `UserDefaults`? Do I have to create a new type that is a clean copy of the above's `DefaultsStorage`, pass mocked `UserDefaults` and test that object?

```swift
struct TestUserDefaultsStorage {
    @DefaultsStorage(key: "userName", storage: UserDefaults(suiteName: #file)!)
    var userName: String?
}
```

Comment: The usual key to mocking is a protocol...

Comment: Do you mean mocking the whole `UserDefaultsStorage`?

Comment: I mean mocking UserDefaults.

Comment: I am sorry but this is exactly what I am failing to achieve.

Comment: But you don't want to mock UserDefaults?

Comment: I do want to mock UserDefaults. I can do that just by passing a different `suiteName` to the initialiser. That would be enough for me. I don't think I need a protocol here. I am just not sure how to make `DefaultsStorage ` work with another instance of UserDefaults.

Comment: Another instance? And passing another argument to the original class is _not_ the same as mocking it.

Answer (score 4):

As @mat already mentioned in the comments, you need a `protocol` to mock `UserDefaults` dependency. Something like this will do:

```
protocol UserDefaultsStorage {
    func value(forKey key: String) -> Any?
    func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)
}

extension UserDefaults: UserDefaultsStorage {}
```

Then you can change your `DefaultsStorage` propertyWrapper to use a `UserDefaultsStorage` reference instead of `UserDefaults`:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct DefaultsStorage<Value> {
    private let key: String
    private let storage: UserDefaultsStorage

    var wrappedValue: Value? {
        get {
            return storage.value(forKey: key) as? Value
        }
        nonmutating set {
            storage.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    init(key: String, storage: UserDefaultsStorage = UserDefaults.standard) {
        self.key = key
        self.storage = storage
    }
}
```

After that a mock `UserDefaultsStorage` might look like this:

```
class UserDefaultsStorageMock: UserDefaultsStorage {
    var values: [String: Any]

    init(values: [String: Any] = [:]) {
        self.values = values
    }

    func value(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        return values[key]
    }

    func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        values[key] = value
    }
}
```

And to test `DefaultsStorage`, pass an instance of `UserDefaultsStorageMock` as its storage parameter:

```
import XCTest

class DefaultsStorageTests: XCTestCase {
    class TestUserDefaultsStorage {
        @DefaultsStorage(
            key: "userName",
            storage: UserDefaultsStorageMock(values: ["userName": "TestUsername"])
        )
        var userName: String?
    }
    
    func test_userName() {
        let testUserDefaultsStorage = TestUserDefaultsStorage()
        
        XCTAssertEqual(testUserDefaultsStorage.userName, "TestUsername")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. This totally makes sense, however I believe this does not answer my first question. How would you test a view model wherein this storage is used without using the `.standard` user defaults?

Comment: @gasho in my example I test `DefaultsStorage`. For your view model to be testable, you have to introduce a new protocol that `DefaultsStorage` should conform to. Your view model should have reference to that protocol instead of `DefaultsStorage` directly and then you will be able to mock `DefaultsStorage` and inject you mock instance to your view model. In general when you want to test something you have to be able to mock all of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best solution, however, I haven't figured out a way to inject `UserDefaults` that use property wrappers into a `ViewModel`. If there is such an option, then [gcharita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6791677/gcharita)'s proposal to use another protocol would be a good one to implement.

I used the same `UserDefaults` in the test class as in the `ViewModel`. I save the original values before each test and restore them after each test.

```
class ViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    
    private lazy var userDefaults = newUserDefaults()
    private var preTestsInitialValues: PreTestsInitialValues!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        savePreTestUserDefaults()
    }
    
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        restoreUserDefaults()
    }
    
    private func newUserDefaults() -> UserDefaults.Type {
        return UserDefaults.self
    }
    
    private func savePreTestUserDefaults() {
        preTestsInitialValues = PreTestsInitialValues(userName: userDefaults.userName)
    }
    
    private func restoreUserDefaults() {
        userDefaults.userName = preTestsInitialValues.userName
    }

    func testUsername() throws {
       //"inject" User Defaults with the desired values
        let username = "No one"
        userDefaults.userName = username
        
        let viewModel = ViewModel()
        let usernameFromViewModel = viewModel.getUserName()
        XCTAssertEqual(username, usernameFromViewModel)
    }
}

struct PreTestsInitialValues {
    let userName: String?
}
```